# how to make menu navigation right align in wordpress theme twenty eleven

Tags: wordpress

I am working in WordPress. I am a newbie. I am trying to make the menu right align. The default menu style is left align what I want is to make it right align so that the whole navigation is right align I have not change any part of styles so assume it that I am using the default style of WordPress twenty eleven theme.

Comment: try changing css : #access div to float right

Comment: ok, your menu structure is like this : http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/

Comment: yes. it is like that except for the header image, i removed it

Comment: but when I try this css from firebug it works and menus are right aligned

Comment: ok let me check at ur url, under which menu this property is at  twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com

Comment: this is the url http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/

Comment: change  #access div to float right in firebug and see

Comment: please help me here, i am unable to find any property in styles at  twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com under menu Showcase...

Comment: Thanks it has worked :) Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post this another post so that i can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing css of  #access div to float right in style.css

```
#access div {
float: right;
margin: 0 7.6%;
```

}